# No output when using nested for loops inside if statements

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to print out a series of patterns based off of the user input. However, when I add an if statement or while loop to it, I get no output even if I selected the correct number. The patterns work if I don't add the loops to it. I'm new to python and don't understand why it isn't printing anything out.

```
num_draw = input("Please enter the number of the design you would like[1-6] or -1 to quit: ")

#while num_draw != -1:
if num_draw == 1:

    for i in range(0, 5):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print("* ",end="")
        print()
elif num_draw == 2:
#2
    size = 5
    isize = size - 2
    print ('*' * size)
    for i in range(isize):
        print ('*' + ' ' * isize + '*')
    print ('*' * size)

elif num_draw == 3:

    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            print(" *"[(j + i + 1)%2], end=' ')
        print()
elif num_draw == 4:

    for i in range(0, 5):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print("* ",end="")
        print()


elif num_draw == 5:
    for i in range(0, 5):
        for j in range(5, i, -1):
            print("@ ", end="")
        print()


elif num_draw == 6:
    k = 8
    for i in range(0, 5):
        for j in range(0, k):
            print(end=" ")
        k = k - 2
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print("* ", end="")
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost correct. The problem was that the keyboard input is always of type `str` (string, by default) and you are comparing it to numbers of type `int` (integer). For ex. if you enter `1`, then `num_draw='1'` and so you are checking `if '1' == 1:` which is `False`. Similarly, none of your `if` or `elif` is `True` because you are comparing `str` type with `int` type.

To make your code work, convert your input type to `int` as follows:

```
num_draw = int(input("Please enter the number of the design you would like[1-6] or -1 to quit: "))
```

**Output**

```
Please enter the number of the design you would like[1-6] or -1 to quit: 

1
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your `input` needs to be an `int` to make proper comparisons.  As for your while loop `while num_draw != -1:` is correct but you need to move your `input` prompt within the loop so user can reelect an option. setting `num_draw = 'x'` is just to create a qualifying condition to start the loop

```
num_draw = 'x'
while num_draw != -1:
    num_draw = int(input("Please enter the number of the design you would like[1-6] or -1 to quit: "))
```